ion-menu not showing after clicking button
I'm working with Angular and trying to add a profile icon to the navbar. This icon should display options when clicking on it. I'm not using the Router outlet to open the menu from another Angular component/page given that I plan to open it in the same component. I tried with contentId, menuId, defining class "ion-page" but nothing seems to work. this is for the webview.
<div class="nav">
  <header>
    <ion-split-pane contentId="profile-menu">
    <div class="profile">
      <ion-buttons  class="ion-page" id="profile-menu"  slot="start" main>
        <ion-button size="large" menuToggle >
          <ion-icon size=""  name="person-outline" ></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
      </ion-buttons> 
    </div>

    <ion-menu  contentId="profile-menu">
      <ion-content>
        <ion-label>HERE</ion-label>
        <ion-list> 
          <ion-menu-toggle>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-label >My profile</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle> 
          <ion-menu-toggle>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-label >Sign out</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle> 
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
  </ion-split-pane>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li class="subdiv">Options</li>
          <li class="subdiv">Memebers</li>
          <li>Requests</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>

